# ¿Cómo guardar el valor o el estado de un control deslizante en Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Actualmante estoy trabjando en un programa en el cual hay varias opciones, entre esas está un control deslizante para modificar un valor por medio de este widget. Por lo tanto ya se cómo guardar el estado de otros widgets como casillas de verficación, botones de radio o entradas de texto con base a respuestas anteriores. He intentado usar otros tipos de variables referentes al widget para poder guardar el estado de control, al analizar el comportamiento del control deslizante con la variable encontré que usando variables enteras o flotantes no hacían ningún efecto.

Este es un breve ejemplo del código en el que estoy trabajando:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root= tk.Tk()
root.geometry('350x140')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Ventana ejemplo escala')

labelValue30per=tk.Label(root, text='30%', font=("Tahoma", 8))
labelValue30per.place(x=25, y=42)

labelValue30per=tk.Label(root, text='100%', font=("Tahoma", 8))
labelValue30per.place(x=260, y=42)

sliderVar = tk.StringVar() #En este caso uso una variable de cadena para probar el comportamiento.

Scale=ttk.Scale(root, from_=30, to_=100, length=190, takefocus=False, command=lambda s:sliderVar.set('%d' % float(s)))
Scale.place(x=62, y=40, height=22)
Scale.set(100)

ShowValueRecent = tk.Label(root, width=4, height=0, bg='white', relief='sunken', textvariable=sliderVar, font=("Tahoma", 8), borderwidth=1)
ShowValueRecent.place(x=300, y=42)

btnClose = tk.Button(root, text='Cerrar', takefocus=False, command=root.destroy, font=("Tahoma", 8), width=11)
btnClose.place(x=250,y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

Por lo tanto mi objetivo actual por medio de esta pregunta es guardar el estado del control deslizante para que luego al volver abrir la ventana se muestre el estado anterior del control deslizante. De antemano agradezco su respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principalmente al ver su pregunta es claro que en caso de algunos widgets como entradas o cuadros de texto se utiliza otro método en el que se basa en definir la variable del widget, leer el archivo de configuración o de texto y guardarlo en ese mismo archivo para que posteriormente al volver a abrir el programa, se asigne el valor que tiene el archivo de texto mediante el método `set()` por medio de la variable del widget. Lo que yo haría en su caso sería usar ese mismo método que yo ya he utilizado en los controles deslizantes, es simple y no requiere tanto código o usar módulos externos para poder guardar el estado del control deslizante.

Básicamente los controles deslizantes se basan más que todo en un comportamiento que es definido por una sola variable y un valor entero, el cual dependiendo del rango asignado la variable define en este caso el valor que se debe mostrar el control deslizante.

**En mi caso esto es lo que haría según su ejemplo:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os

root= tk.Tk()
root.geometry('350x140')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Ventana ejemplo escala')

labelValue30per=tk.Label(root, text='30%', font=("Tahoma", 8))
labelValue30per.place(x=25, y=42)

labelValue30per=tk.Label(root, text='100%', font=("Tahoma", 8))
labelValue30per.place(x=260, y=42)

sliderVar = tk.StringVar() #En este caso uso una variable de cadena para probar el comportamiento.

Scale=ttk.Scale(root, from_=30, to_=100, length=190, takefocus=False, command=lambda s:sliderVar.set('%d' % float(s))) # Control deslizante (variable flotante, solo enteros)
Scale.place(x=62, y=40, height=22)
Scale.set(100) 

if os.path.isfile('SaveScale.ini'): # Leer el archivo de configuración para reconfigurar el estado del control deslizante
    with open('SaveScale.ini','r') as fileScaleRead:
        sliderVar.set(fileScaleRead.read())  # Usar variable para poder leer el archivo y posterior reconfigurar el valor de control deslizante
        Scale.set(sliderVar.get()) # Establecer el valor de la escala que se obtuvo en la variable del control deslizante

ShowValueRecent = tk.Label(root, width=4, height=0, bg='white', relief='sunken', textvariable=sliderVar, font=("Tahoma", 8), borderwidth=1)
ShowValueRecent.place(x=300, y=42) # Establece y actualiza el valor actual del control deslizante al moverlo mediante la variable del control deslizante

def saveScaleValue():
    with open('SaveScale.ini','w') as fileSaveScale: #Guardará el valor de la escala, si hace clic en 'Cerrar'.
        fileSaveScale.write(sliderVar.get()) # Asignar valor de la escala en un archivo de configuración para que lo lea después

btnClose = tk.Button(root, text='Cerrar', takefocus=False, command=lambda:[saveScaleValue(), root.destroy()], font=("Tahoma", 8), width=11)
btnClose.place(x=250,y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

Este tipo de solución es la más viable y la que más eficiente si quiere guardar el estado del control deslizante.

**Para evidenciar los resultados:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Era justo lo que necesitaba, en general su respuesta contesta mi pregunta y su explicación me ayudó para poder entender y comprender el problema que tenía, muchas gracias de nuevo.